# I updated silverlight and now VS 2010 won't load Silverlight project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I updated Silverlight because IE was continuously bugging me to update it to new version. And so I did. But after doing it my silvelright application gives me this message:

[image]

When I click this link and try to install Silverlight Developer runtime, it says its already installed. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s try restarting in a clean boot, uninstalling Silverlight, checking program files to make sure there is no Silverlight folder, run Windows Installer CleanUp Utility, and then download Silverlight.

[Here is the step by step process](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie8-silverlight-silverlight-repeatedly-prompts-to/a1bc911f-fe22-4095-a5a4-7adb71b47d0f?auth=1) May be it'll help you.